# Using data i get from request function in node.JS again until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request

I want to access shopify api using Node.js with request method. I get first 50 items but i need to send the last id of the products i get as a response so it can loop through all the products until we don't have another id (i check that if the last array is not 50 in length.)

So when i get the response of lastID i want to feed that again to the same function until the Parraylength is not 50 or not 0.

Thing is request works asynchronously and i don't know how to feed the same function with the result lastID in node.js.

Here is my code

````
let importedData = JSON.parse(body);


 //for ( const product in importedData.products ){
  //  console.log(`${importedData.products[product].id}`);    
 //}
 lastID = importedData.products[importedData.products.length-1].id;
 let lastIDD = lastID;
 console.log(`This is ${lastID}`);
 importedData ? console.log('true') : console.log('false');
 let Prarraylength = importedData.products.length;
 console.log(Prarraylength); 
 //console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
 return lastIDD;

});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop and *await* to control the flow of your script in this case.

I'd suggest using the [request-native-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) module to get items, since it has a promise based interface, but you could use node-fetch or axios (or any other http client) too.

In this case, to show you the logic, I've created a mock rp which normally you'd create as follows:

```
const rp = require("request-promise-native");
```

You can see we're looping through the items, 50 at a time. We're passing the last id as a url parameter to the next rp call. Now this is obviously going to be different in reality, but I believe you can easily change the logic as you require.

```js
const totalItems = 155;
const itemsPerCall = 50;

// Mock items array...
const items = Array.from({ length: totalItems}, (v,n) => { return { id: n+1, name: `item #${n+1}` } });

// Mock of request-promise (to show logic..)
// Replace with const rp = require("request-promise-native");
const rp = function(url) {
    let itemPointer = parseInt(url.split("/").slice(-1)[0]);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let slice = items.slice(itemPointer, itemPointer + itemsPerCall);
            itemPointer += itemsPerCall;
            resolve( { products: slice });
        }, 500); 
    })    
}

async function getMultipleRequests() {
    let callIndex = 0;
    let lastID = 0;
    const MAX_CALLS = 20; 
    const EXPECTED_ARRAY_LENGTH = 50;
    
    for(let callCount = 1; callCount < MAX_CALLS; callCount++) {
        // Replace with the actual url..
        let url = "/products/" + lastID;
        let importedData = await rp(url);
        lastID = importedData.products[importedData.products.length - 1].id;
        console.log("Call #: " + ++callIndex + ", Item count: " + importedData.products.length +  ", lastID: " + lastID);
        if (importedData.products.length < EXPECTED_ARRAY_LENGTH) {
            console.log("Reached the end of products...exiting loop...");
            break;
        }
    }
}

getMultipleRequests();
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! Although i just used shopify-api-node now and works out of the box. Considering this a good answer using it without the shopify api package :D